# The name above already exists on npm, choose another?

Tags: npm, yeoman

I'm trying to use a yeoman generator I've created.

I have installed the generator generator with

```
 npm install -g generator-generator
```

I have a git-hub account

If I type

```
yo generator
```

I can add my Github username and the name of the generator, then I get the message.

```
The name above already exists on npm, choose another.
```

Answer (score 0):

[`generator-generator`](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-generator) is for creating your own generators. It's necessary that your intended generator name be available on `npm`, so users may install it. The error is telling you that the name you've chosen is not available on `npm`.